# Conditions for principal divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $C$ is a complex riemann surface and $D$ a general divisor on $C$. Is there a way to say that this divisor is principal, i.e. $D$ is the divisor of a meromorphic function on $C$? I ask this question because i see that the picard group of the comlec riemann sphere is trivial.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Do you mean "is there an algorithm"?  Do you mean "what is the picard group"?

Comment: i mean are there some algebraic conditions that tells me that $D$ is principal?

Comment: if you have a divisor what kind of ways can you follow to verify that D is principal or not?